# Test subscribing to Location in angular 2 with karma+jasmine (this.location.subscribe)

Tags: angular, karma-jasmine, angular-test

I am subscribing to the [angular Location service](https://angular.io/api/common/Location#subscribe) in my component as such:

```
this.location.subscribe((ev:PopStateEvent) => {
    this.lastPoppedUrl = ev.url;
});
```

I'd like to be able to test it along with the rest of my component.

Right now I have this stub in my component.spec.ts file

```
let locationStub: Partial<Location>;
    locationStub = {
}
```

And I am configuring it into my TestBed as a provider:

```
{provide: Location, useValue: locationStub }
```

When I run `ng test`, I get this error `this.location.subscribe is not a function`.

How can I create a stub or spy that will allow me to pass the .subscribe functionality of Location.

[Here is a similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41982166/how-to-test-location-in-angular-2-with-karmajasmine) on testing Location, but it is referring to functions within Location, not specifically subscribing to Location.

Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to do it like this:

```
beforeEach(() => {
    // Mock the location here instead, then pass to the NavBarComponent
    loc = jasmine.createSpyObj("Location", ["back", "subscribe"]);
    Location.subscribe.and.callFake(()=> Observable.of(your stubbed data to return here));
    testNavBarComponent = new NavBarComponent(loc);
});
```

So you have to add `subscribe` to the list of the available functions in the Location service.

And it's important to tell what to return then when calling the subscribe,

This is what `Location.subscribe.and.callFake(()=> Observable.of(Your stubbed data to return here));` is for.

I've tried to create a small demo:

Here is the link to it, you can try to fork and modify it as needed.

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-testing-c25ezq?file=app/app.component.spec.ts