# Undefined is not an object(evaluating 'this.outages.getValues) in karma (Angular 2)

Tags: angular, unit-testing, karma-jasmine, angular-test

I'm trying to fix this for the past 3 hours and no use. Any help would be appreciated.

This is my component

```
export class CallComponent implements OnInit{

    ngOnInit() {
        this.initCall();
    }
    constructor(
                private chat: ChatActiveService,
                private monitor: MonitorService,
                private outages: OutagesService) {
    }

    initCall() {

        // Make 3 calls simultaneously


            const combined = forkJoin (

            this.chat.callA(param).pipe(
                catchError(err => { 
                    this.handleConversationError(err);
                    return Observable.empty();
                }),
            ),

            this.monitor.callB().pipe(
                catchError(err => {
                    return Observable.empty();
                })
            ), 
            this.outages.getValues().pipe(
                catchError(err => {
                    return Observable.empty();
                    //return Observable.of(undefined);
                })
            )
        );

        const subscribe = combined.subscribe (
            ([ callA, callB, getValues ]) => {
               //  My actions
            }
        );
    }
```

In my spec file, i imported the services, added the services in providers and i added mock data also for the functions. I'm getting this error

```
Undefined is not an object(evaluating 'this.outages.getValues)
```

The implementation done in my component is wrong or should i add anything else?

Any idea or suggestion would be appreciated!

Comment: Edit and add your spec file to the question. You most likely didn't mock correctly your service in the test. look to this question if it can help: [test-subscribing-to-location-in-angular-2-with-karmajasmine-this-location-subs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49581616/test-subscribing-to-location-in-angular-2-with-karmajasmine-this-location-subs)