# how to check subscribe function is working in angular?

Tags: javascript, angular

I want to unit test of my function which is present in component using jasmine.
Inside that function `subscribe` function is present .I want to test that function id user get response than it should navigate to `/user` component.

**function**

```
 onSubmit(val) {
    console.log(val);
    this.signupService.signUpHandler(val).subscribe((res:SignUpModel) => {
      if (res.token !== '') {
        this.router.navigate(['/users']);
      }
    }, (err) => {
      console.log(err);
    });
  }
```

here is my code
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-testing-kdb8ka?file=app%2Fapp.component.ts

I am able to check my `service` function is called on button click

```
 it('should called service method on button click', inject([SignupserviceService], (signupserviceService: SignupserviceService) => {
      spyOn(signupserviceService, 'signUpHandler');
      let button = fixture.nativeElement.querySelector('.btn')
      button.click();
      expect(signupserviceService.signUpHandler).toHaveBeenCalled();
    }));
```

Now I want to check if I got response from service than I will redirect to `\user` component.

Comment: maybe just `spyOn().and.callFake(() => Observable.of('xxx'))` to make sure it's an observable that you can subscribe to ?

Comment: can you please give some code

Comment: May be similar to : [test-subscribing-to-location-in-angular-2-with-karmajasmine-this-location-subs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49581616/test-subscribing-to-location-in-angular-2-with-karmajasmine-this-location-subs/49582483#49582483)

Answer (score 1):

You just need to spy on the function you are subscribing to and return the response you would expect, assuming success:

```
it('should call the router's navigate method if a non-empty string token property is on the response', inject([SignupserviceService, Router], (signupserviceService: SignupserviceService, router: Router) => {
      spyOn(signupserviceService, 'signUpHandler').and.returnValue(Observable.of({token: 'not empty'}));
      spyOn(router, 'navigate');
      let button = fixture.nativeElement.querySelector('.btn');

      button.click();
      expect(router.navigate).toHaveBeenCalledWith(['/users']);
    })
);
```

Treat this as pseudo-code, as I haven't checked it for errors, but you get the idea.

Comment: I think it is better to try to create a complete demo, when possible, to make the answer well understood. to benefit more peoples that may have the same issue as well.

Comment: That is a fair point....I will try to update the answer this evening to be more complete.